# Delete different named folders using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

I've been doing a little research, and I haven't find anything remotely similar to what I'm looking at, so here's my case:
I have a folder, lets name it **MasterFolder**
So, lets say that my MasterFolder, has inside of it, four more folders, I know I can use

```
cd C:\MasterFolder\
```

to leave my CMD console just on top of those so, for didactic meanings, lets call them:

```
 - Folder_A
 - Folder_B
 - Folder_C
 - Folder_D
```

So, inside each of those folders, there are even more folders, that are named

```
 "EncodingMaster_Originals"
```

the name is the same for all, so, that way, we could say that the folders are, for example:

```
 - Folder_A\EncodingMaster_Originals (and OTHER files that I won't delete)
 - Folder_B\InsideFolder_B\EncodingMaster_Originals (In another folder inside Folder_B
```

Those two are the most simple examples.

So, what I want to do?

Well, is simple, I just want to delete the folder named

```
"EncodingMaster_Originals"
```

from each of the folders, without having to be going into each one (There's around 200 folders with those little ones inside, I've made some massive re-encoding of files, and those folders appeared from nowhere).

I think that I've to use this line of code:

```
rd
```

(the Remove directory command), but my problem is that I don't know what I have to tell to the RD command, I don't want to look more dumb so I won't type what I've tried, because it was obviously wrong.

If you could help me, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

So, after a brief search with a different bunch of words. I found THIS post:
[How to remove all folders of name x within a directory using cmd/batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393082/how-to-remove-all-folders-of-name-x-within-a-directory-using-cmd-batch-file?rq=1)

And the answer is this comment:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10399706/4625105

Thanks if you were about to answer, I think the case is closed.